# Vulkan swapchain format UNORM to SRGB using VK_KHR_swapchain_mutable_format?

Tags: vulkan

**Creating swapchain images with wrong format** result this obviously:

```
vkCreateImageView() format VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM differs from VkImage 
0x40000000004[] format VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB.  Formats MUST be IDENTICAL unless 
VK_IMAGE_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT BIT was set on image creation.
```

[VK_KHR_swapchain_mutable_format](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_swapchain_mutable_format.html) Requires Vulkan 1.0

it result this:

```
The Vulkan spec states: If flags contains VK_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT_KHR 
then the pNext chain must include a VkImageFormatListCreateInfo structure with a viewFormatCount 
greater than zero and pViewFormats must have an element equal to imageFormat
```

[VkImageFormatListCreateInfo](https://khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkImageFormatListCreateInfoKHR.html) Provided by VK_VERSION_1_2

**Question** - how Vulkan 1.0 extension require 1.2 structure? (maybe I'm missing something idk)

And as I see on https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listextensions.php VK_KHR_swapchain_mutable_format supported only by 60% of Vulkan GPUs... **so better write "hand conversion"?**

Comment: Does the device only support UNORM? Couldn't you ask for SRGB instead?

Comment: asking SRGB against Vulkan specs, Vulkan return swapchain image format that UNORM or SRGB or something else, if I ask SRGB-everything will work, but Validation layers not happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VkImageFormatListCreateInfo Provided by VK_VERSION_1_2

You linked to the Vulkan 1.2 specification. So of course it cites *itself*. The extension in question is a core part of 1.2, as is `VkImageFormatListCreateInfo`.

The actual [*extension*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_swapchain_mutable_format.html) cites another extension:

> Requires [VK_KHR_image_format_list](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_image_format_list.html)

Which defines the `VkImageFormatListCreateInfoKHR` structure used by the swapchain format extension. This structure is of course equivalent to the core 1.2 structure `VkImageFormatListCreateInfo`, since "image_format_list" was promoted to core in Vulkan 1.2.